# aws xgboost - lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, xgboost

I'm trying to run the `xgboost` algorithm on data I send from lambda.

How should I send the body?

I know I should use CSV format, but I can't figure out how to make a CSV from my data set,

This is the code:

```py
result = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, Body=**????**, 
        ContentType='text/csv'
      );
```

This is my data test:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "Utilizing_card_1": 0.6,
    "Utilizing_card_2": 0.7,
    "Utilizing_card_3": 0.6,
    "Utilizing_card_4": 0.5,
    "perc_private": 0.5,
    "perc_proff": 0.7
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If lambda is just returning the data for you to run through a model have lambda return the data in json then use pythons json library to load it as a dictionary convert the dictionary to a dataframe and go from there if lambda is running the model just send it a pickled dictionary then have lambda convert it back then to dataframe.

There is no "invoke_endpoint" for lambda. Are you trying to use lambda to call the SageMaker Runtime Invoke_Endpoint?

if so there are some [good tutorials](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)